# Use assignment operator with subscript operator to assign value to std::map

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, sparse-matrix

I have a Matrix class

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:
  const size_t rows;
  const size_t cols;
  const std::map<std::array<int, 2>, T> data;

  Matrix(int a, int b) : rows(a), cols(b)
  {
  }
};
```

which is initialized like this:

```
Matrix<double> M(5,5);
```

creating a 5x5 matrix.

I want to assign values to the map like so:

```
M[{1,2}] = 1;
```

How would I go about doing that in the most readable way? I'm not sure how to get the subscript and assignment operator working together.

Comment: "How would I go about doing that in the most readable way?" first of all by making data non const.

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969881/operator-overload) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27221482/5267751).

Comment: A std::map as matrix is a bad implementation.

Comment: @manni66 not according to my literature when dealing with sparse matrices

Comment: @Ortix92 I would be interested in seeing that literature.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it's on my scientific computing class' slides and in the reader, so I'll stick with that  for now. I know there are far superior methods and I don't like reinventing the wheel either, but it's what I have to deal with now.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it's overkill for `M(5,5)`, but is more obviously useful for `M(500000,500000)`

Comment: @Caleth I don't see how. Calculating an index in a flat vector and accessing the element is constant time. Accessing an element in a `std::map` has logarithmic time complexity. Meaning that `std::vector` becomes a more attractive solution as the size of the matrix grows.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux not for **sparse** matrices

Comment: @bolov Thanks, I missed that part of the context.

Comment: I would recommend replacing `std::array<int, 2>` with `std::pair<int, int>`

Comment: @bolov I would recommend making a separate class for this

Comment: I actually think OP is fine with `std::array<int, 2>` here, all they need is something that can be list initialized with 2 indexes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's add some helper aliases to `Matrix` while we are at it

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix
{   
    // rather than stoping people changing the members via const
    // make them private
    size_t rows;
    size_t cols;
    map_type data;
public:
    using key_type = std::array<size_t, 2>;
    using mapped_type = T;
    using map_type = std::map<key_type, mapped_type>;

    Matrix(size_t r, size_t c) : rows(r), cols(c) { }

    const T& operator [](key_type key) const { return data[key]; }
          T& operator [](key_type key)       { return data[key]; }

    // other operations as appropriate
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide members:

```
const T& operator [](std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>) const;
      T& operator [](std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to go from here, could you be a bit more specific?